# How fix "Argument 'Expression' cannot be converted to type 'RadioButton' in VB simple calculator

Tags: vb.net

I want to create this calculator
[Final result should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MhiH.png)

But when I code the "Calculate" button shows in the above image, with this code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCal.Click
    Dim fun As String

    If Val(radAdd) = True Then
        txtResult.Text = Val(txtIn1.Text) + Val(txtIn2.Text)
    ElseIf Val(radSub) = True Then
        txtResult.Text = Val(txtIn1.Text) - Val(txtIn2.Text)
    ElseIf Val(radMul) = True Then
        txtResult.Text = Val(txtIn1.Text) * Val(txtIn2.Text)
    ElseIf Val(radDiv) = True Then
        txtResult.Text = Val(txtIn1.Text) / Val(txtIn2.Text)
    ElseIf Val(radRem) = True Then
        txtResult.Text = Val(txtIn1.Text) % Val(txtIn2.Text)
    ElseIf Val(radexp) = True Then
        Dim num As Integer
        Dim expo As Integer
        Dim result As Integer

        num = Val(txtIn1.Text)
        expo = Val(txtIn2.Text)
        result = Math.Pow(num, expo)
        txtResult.Text = result

    ElseIf Val(radMax) = True Then
        If Val(txtIn1.Text) > Val(txtIn2.Text) Then
            txtResult.Text = txtIn1.Text
        Else
            txtResult.Text = txtIn2.Text
        End If
    ElseIf Val(radmin) = True Then
        If Val(txtIn1.Text) < Val(txtIn2.Text) Then
            txtResult.Text = txtIn1.Text
        Else
            txtResult.Text = txtIn1.Text
        End If
    Else
        txtResult.Text = "Invalid input"
    End If
End Sub
```

And then run the program it's working, but when after selected the "Radio Button" and click Calculate" button It's showing the error "Argument 'Expression' cannot be converted to type 'RadioButton"

I couldn't understand the problem. Anyone can help me to solve this It's huge for me.
Thank you!

Comment: `Val(txtIn1) > Val(txtIn2)` should be `Val(txtIn1.Text) > Val(txtIn2.Text)`. Please have a look at your use of `Val(...)` at several places. You are passing the control instead of the text of the control.

Comment: @SebastianSiemens Thank you. I fix it now. But still, the same error occurs.

Comment: You're trying to extract a value from the instance of an object instead of the value of one of its Properties (`.Text` of a TextBox, `.Checked` of a RadioButton etc.). E.g., this: `If Val(radAdd) = True` doesn't make any sense. Set `Option Strict ON` and fix all the problems that are now *visible*.

Comment: `Val` is not a good choice for modern VB, as it is a VBA legacy-support function that has some behaviors that may be surprising.  I would strongly recommend to switch to using the appropriate `Parse` or `TryParse` method, probably `Double.Parse` or `Double.TryParse`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about your program. I also did not test my code.
Please have a look at your use of `Val()`: you are passing the instance of a Control instead of a Property value, several times.

You need to test `RadioButton.Checked`, not `Val(RadioButton)`, e.g.:

```
If radAdd.Checked = True Then [...] End If
```

Here is my solution:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCal.Click
    Dim fun As String

    If radAdd.Checked = True Then
        txtResult.Text = Val(txtIn1.Text) + Val(txtIn2.Text)
    ElseIf radSub.Checked = True Then
        txtResult.Text = Val(txtIn1.Text) - Val(txtIn2.Text)
    ElseIf radMul.Checked = True Then
        txtResult.Text = Val(txtIn1.Text) * Val(txtIn2.Text)
    ElseIf radDiv.Checked = True Then
        txtResult.Text = Val(txtIn1.Text) / Val(txtIn2.Text)
    ElseIf radRem.Checked = True Then
        txtResult.Text = Val(txtIn1.Text) % Val(txtIn2.Text)
    ElseIf radexp.Checked = True Then
        Dim num As Integer
        Dim expo As Integer
        Dim result As Integer

        num = Val(txtIn1.Text)
        expo = Val(txtIn2.Text)
        result = Math.Pow(num, expo)
        txtResult.Text = result

    ElseIf radMax.Checked = True Then
        If Val(txtIn1.Text) > Val(txtIn2.Text) Then
            txtResult.Text = txtIn1.Text
        Else
            txtResult.Text = txtIn2.Text
        End If
    ElseIf radmin.Checked = True Then
        If Val(txtIn1.Text) < Val(txtIn2.Text) Then
            txtResult.Text = txtIn1.Text
        Else
            txtResult.Text = txtIn1.Text
        End If
    Else
        txtResult.Text = "Invalid input"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `Val` method left over from VB6. It can give unexpected results. `Integer.Parse` will validate the input and fill the variable you provide with an `Integer`. I separated the code into separate methods instead of doing too many things in a single method.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim FirstValue As Integer
    Dim SecondValue As Integer
    Dim rb As RadioButton
    If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, FirstValue) AndAlso Integer.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, SecondValue) Then
        rb = GetSelectedRadioButton(Me)
        Dim result = GetResult(rb.Text, FirstValue, SecondValue)
        TextBox3.Text = result.ToString
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number in both boxes")
    End If
End Sub

Public Function GetSelectedRadioButton(Container As Control) As RadioButton
    Dim rb = Container.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton)().FirstOrDefault(Function(r) r.Checked = True)
    Return rb
End Function

Private Function GetResult(RadioButtonText As String, Val1 As Integer, Val2 As Integer) As Double
    Dim result As Double
    Select Case RadioButtonText
        Case "ADDITION"
            result = Val1 + Val2
        Case "SUTRACTION"
            result = Val1 - Val2
        Case "MUPTIPLICATION"
            result = Val1 * Val2
        Case "DIVISION"
            result = Val1 / Val2
        Case "REMAINDER"
            result = Val1 Mod Val2
        Case "EXPONENT"
            result = Val1 ^ Val2
        Case "MAX()"
            If Val1 > Val2 Then
                result = Val1
            Else
                result = Val2
            End If
        Case "MIN()"
            If Val1 < Val2 Then
                result = Val1
            Else
                result = Val2
            End If
    End Select
    Return result
End Function
```

Note: Correct the spelling of Remainder.